# Why the random forest (ranger function) returns a r.squared null

Tags: r, random-forest

I write this question because I use the random forest algorithm from the `ranger` package in R. My model is this:

```
    library(ranger)
    ...
    data manipulation
    ...
    model_rf<-ranger(formula = as.factor(bg_variable) ~., data = x_train,
                   num.trees = 100,
                   min.node.size = 80000,
                   probability = T,
                   importance = 'impurity')
```

My target variabile is a factor and is a boolean (1 bad result, 0 good result).
I'd like to see the r.squared but, when I call it the results is null, why?
Where I mistake?
Other the r.suared I take look to the `Gini` index(`0.1375` I know that is low, but my db is not the best)  and to the `prediction.error` (`0.03076395`).
The is: why my r.squared is null?

```
model_rf$r.squared
NULL
```

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

> r.squared: R squared.  Also called explained variance or coefficient of
> determination (regression only). Computed on out of bag data.

So `r.squared` is returned only for numeric (in R jargon) target variables.
Since yours is a factor, R² is not returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. 
Could you suggest me other test that I can do?

Comment: This is a fraught question - which test.  It is like asking a random stranger to kiss your spouse, or more precisely it is like being asked by a random couple to kiss one of them.  It is an intimate thing.  In statistical problem solving the first thing you do is understand your problem and determine the nature of the tests you are going to use to answer your question or achieve your result.  I like Cohen's kappa for classification, but if you have a pointy-haired boss then you might find that intractable. Do you have an intuition that augments understanding of its use?  If not its fraught.